# sending increment value from jquery to php file with for loop help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, for-loop, parameter-passing

I have this for loop in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        for(i=0; i<counter; i++)
        {
            dataCounter = i;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'file.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: dataCounter,
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error loading XML document');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#contents").html(data);  
                }
            });
        }
});
```

And then I want to bring in my dataCounter into the file.php as a variable and have it change each time so I can get different records in mysql in file.php, am I doing this right? How would the php portion look like? I know how pass variables to a php file with this method if I had a form, but I don't have a get or a post form to work with. Also, my variables are going to change.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't recommend running an ajax query inside of a loop, I am wiling to explain the `data` option for `$.ajax()`. Ideally, you pass an object as the `data` option, and it is translated by jQuery into a query string where each object property name is a key and its value is the value:

```
data: {
  count: dataCounter
}
```

becomes

```
?count=1
```

in the query string of the ajax request if `datacounter` is equal to 1.

In PHP you would access it as `$_GET['count']`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. If you don't recommend running an ajax query inside of a loop, can you give me any suggestions on what I should do instead? Thank you

Comment: In order to avoid pounding your server with http requests, perhaps you could run the loop to determine the range which dataCounter will cover, then send that range info in an ajax request and let PHP loop over the range. **Edit:** this is just one suggestion, and I don't know what your full situation is to know whether it is viable. Maybe your loop isn't as big a problem as I imagine, but it seems potentially dangerous.

Comment: yeah i was just going to loop like 5 increments or so. maybe at most 10

Answer (score 2):

data needs to be a key-value pair, not just a value as you have it here. Try something like: (not tested)

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'file.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: ({dataCounter : dataCounter}),
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error loading XML document');
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#contents").html(data);  
                }
            });
```

Comment: +1 You beat me. :) Personally, though, I wouldn't wrap it parens.